# Can single PeerConnection have multiple DataChannels?

Tags: webrtc

Can I create multiple datachannels for one PeerConnection ?
Can you provide example as to how it can be achieved, else reason why it is not possible?

Comment: i thought answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507934/how-to-webrtc-datachannel-close) already shows how to create multiple datachannels, or you want something else?

Comment: @kyunghwanjung Every data channel is associated with an RTCPeerConnection, and each peer connection can have up to a **theoretical maximum** of `65,534` data channels (the actual limit may vary from browser to browser). This same concept is acceptable to every platform such as **Android, iOS, Desktop, Browsers** when you are working with WebRtc PeerConnections. Visit: [RTCDataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple data channels on a single peer connection:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
var dc = pc.createDataChannel("my channel");
var dc2 = pc.createDataChannel("my other channel");
```

Answer (score -3):

You can emulate this behaviour by opening up many one-to-one WebRTC connections.

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) discusses many connections going though a MCU server.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You don't need multiple connections or an MCU.

Comment: @kyunghwanjung Multiple connections is a very bad approach when you can simply do the same with a single connection. xdumaine's answer is the correct one!

Comment: @kyunghwanjung Care to clarify your question with a use case? I assumed you wanted to have many different browsers connected P2P, this is what I have done before and for each client I had to create a separate PeerConnection & DataChannel.

Comment: @obscure-geek it is not a very bad approach it is an approach that would work well, I do agree with you though, however some people may not want to have to implement the multiplexing logic required when using the same DataChannel.

Comment: @jamcoope The question clearly states that can a single PeerConnection have multiple DataChannels. Isn't creating multiple connections contradicting the question in the first place?

Comment: @jamcoope thank you anwser one peerConnection use one datachannel that should I?

Comment: Yes depending on your use case. But as @xdumaine pointed out you can actually create multiple DataChannels for a single PeerConnection, however this PeerConnection is with the same browser. If you want multiple browsers all connected to each other then you need to create multiple PeerConnections each with DataChannel(s).